# UITableView Section Header Jumps during navigation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a UINavigationController. when I click to push another view onto the stack, the section header jumps down, and then when I go back after a little while it jumps back up.
Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Have you set up constraints in autolayout?
The constraints get broken after animation.

Comment: Are you changing "**Adjust Scrollview Insets**"?

Comment: I'm not changing `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` in the child view controller. I am using auto layout as follows. I have a UITableView that is initialized like so: `[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain]` and then I am using AutoLayoutDSL as follows to have the table view fill the entire view:
`self.tableView.left == View().left;
self.tableView.right == View().right;
self.tableView.top == View().top;
self.tableView.bottom == View().bottom;`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I inadvertently placed a network request in my updateViewCondtraints method, when the request finished it was calling [tableView reloadData] which is what causes it. Sorry for the dumb question